# To get the value from particular hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the below code i have a hidden field.Now i want to get the value from the particular hidden field.I tried the below code i get all the hidden field values.But i want the particular hidden field value.Pls help me to do this.
JS:

```
str = "";
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function (){
   str+=$(this).val() + "$";
  });
if(str != "")
  str = str.substring(0,str.length-1);

alert(str);
```

asp.net

```
<asp:hiddenfield ID="hide" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the client id of the field you want as the selector:

```
<asp:hiddenfield ID="hide" ClientID="hide" runat="server"/>

var hiddenFieldValue = $('#hide').val();
```

Comment: with respect to ASP.Net, may be the OP needs `ClientID`, since the hidden field doesn't have `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Answer (score 2):

why not just use the id selector of the hidden field?

```
$('#hide').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access a particular field based on the ID as shown in other answer. But since your control doesn't specify `ClientIDMode` you would need:

```
var hiddenField = $('#' + <%= hide.ClientID %>).val();
```

Or you can specify [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `static` *(if you are using ASP.Net 4.0 or higher)* like:

```
<asp:hiddenfield ID="hide" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"/>
```

and then:

```
var hiddenField = $('#hide').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your hidden field and then find it on the client side by that id.

```
<asp:hiddenfield ID="hide" ClientID="myHiddenField" runat="server"/>
```

Client-side Javascript:

```
var myHiddenField = $("#myHiddenField");
```

Or you can set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to static and then use `ID` instead.